# Rounding Pi in Perl to the 100 millionth decimal place?

Tags: perl, rounding, pi

For a Science Fair project, I am testing how your choice of programming language could affect performance. I am doing this by making scripts in Java, Ruby, Perl, and Python to calculate Pi to the 100 millionth decimal place. I'm starting with Perl, since I'm most familiar with Perl. However, this brings an interesting problem to the table. I need to round Pi to the 100 millionth digit in Perl, but as far as I can see, Perl has no good rounding method for this situation. There's only stuff like

```
use Math::Round;
$rounded = nearest(0.1, $numb);
```

And that's a bit of a problem, since I don't want to sit at my computer typing 100 million zeros. As far as I know, sprintf and printf aren't any better; plus, they have that annoying half to even thing. Can anyone help out?

P.S. I'm planning to use the Chudnovsky Formula, if it matters to anyone.

Comment: for what you need such big accuracy? it's surprising

Comment: @loldop, that seems clear from the question: it's an exercise to demonstrate programming techniques/performance.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think any programming language can natively do what you are asking. Even bignum libraries like Math::BigRat (default 40 digits) and Math::Bignum cannot do 100 million digits.

To make it happen, you will have to create your own custom way to represent such big numbers and how to round them.

Answer (score 3):

Think about the problem in another way. You need to round to 100 million (1E8) digits but you don't need to process all 1E8 digits in one go to do that.

Instead,

1. Use the Chudnovsky Formula to calculate 1E8 +1 digits.
2. Store the digits in a string (if you have the memory) or a file.
3. Select the last n (something small like 8 or even 2) digits.
4. If they aren't all 9 round to n-1 digits.
5. If they are then convert them to (n-1) * 0 digits. Then read the next n digits from the end and repeat 4 and 5.

However, if the goal is to test relative performance of languages by generating 1E8 digits of Pi then why bother focus on the rather artificial constraint of rounding that number. If you use the same algorithm then any language should produce the same result. And you have a 50% chance of generating a rounded number anyway.

Comment: I have to do it like that because in science, you have to have everything constant except for the independent variable, which is the programming language of choice here. Everything else, including the amount of Pi calculated should be the same. Therefore, I have to make sure each script calculates the same numbers of Pi.

Answer (score 2):

This is one step closer (though I haven't tested whether it can handle 100 million zeros). You'll need to use [bignum](https://metacpan.org/module/bignum) to handle those sorts of numbers.

```
use bignum;
use Math::Round;

$rounded = nearest(1e-100_000_001, $numb);
```

Also, `bignum` has its own `pi` function with an accuracy parameter:

```
$rounded = bignum::bpi(100_000_001);
```

Comment: While it theoretically can, in practice I don't think that the algorithm Math::BigFloat (the module behind `bignum`) uses an efficient enough algorithm for it to be useful to 100 million digits.